# Google Play, version codes, and APK expansion files

Tags: android, google-play, apk, apk-expansion-files

On Google Play lets say I publish an APK app with version code = 1, and I also publish a related APK expansion file. Now at some later stage I publish a new APK app with version code 2. Will the old APK expansion file (i.e. the one related to version code = 1) still be available for the old APK app?

Further will Google Play allow me to publish an APK app with the same version code as an already existing app? For example by deleting the old APK (version code = 1) and then publish a new APK (still with version code = 1)?

Comment: You cannot delete an apk. You can only unpublish. It remains in your account and you cannot upload another apk with the same version code.

Comment: Thanks Kuffs. Playing a little bit with Google Play I can see, you are right. Do you have a comment on my first question? What happends if an APK with version code = 1 is installed, and somehow the related APK expansion file is not installed (e.g. due to no external storage). Now a new APK with version code = 2 is published. Will the old APK expansion file still be available for the old APK with version code = 1, or will the old APK download the new APK expansion file related to the APK with version code = 2?

Comment: I didn't comment on that because I have no idea. Never used expansion files. Just try it and see what happens. Don't forget to come back and post your findings so others can learn from your experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that one APK version is linked to its related APK expansion file i.e. if APK with version code = 1 is installed, but the related expansion file is not downloaded for whatever reason, then it can still get its related expansion file (version code = 1), even if the APK is unpublished on Google Play due to a newer APK with version code = 2 is uploaded and published. Users installing the new APK (version code = 2) will naturally get the expansion file for that version code.

Please remember that the (main) expansion file has the name:

```
main.<version code>.<package name>.obb
```

i.e. the version code is part of the name.